# Android RecyclerView: row swipe on click

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I've created recyclerView with swipe listener to show backround with undo button after swiping row sideways. It's working fine but I want to do this swipe programaticaly when user clicks row. When I was looking for something that would help I found just libraries to override animations. But how can I set my own animator to swipe row of recyclerView when user just click on it?

Can you please link me to some useful examples or explain me any way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **[ItemAnimator library](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators)** for achieveing animations for recyclerview.